# Easiest way to copy an inline image from org mode to clipboard in Doom emacs

Tags: copy-paste, doom

Easiest way to copy an inline image from org mode to clipboard.

I tried ox-clip, but when hovering over the image i get:

```
funcall-interactively: Symbol’s value as variable is void: org-html-inline-image-rules
```

What am i doing wrong or is there an easier solution?

Comment: Try `M-x load-library RET ox-html RET` and see if you can get ox-clip to work.

Comment: Works! Thinks so much @NickD

Comment: If you keep having this problem, you can add `(require 'ox-html)` to your init file (although you really shouldn't have to).